# CSS / border-image / border-image-slice / causing very small gaps like division lines

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following code:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>border-image slice issue</title>
<style type="text/css">
.container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 344px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 245, 187);
}
.frame {
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 800px;
  height: 1000px;
  background-image: url('https://i.ibb.co/wQSgvS7/jessica.jpg'), url('https://i.ibb.co/1ssy41c/mcol-papyrus-bg.png');
  background-size: 500px 700px, auto;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;
  border-width: 0;
  border-image: url('https://i.ibb.co/N22Y8qg/fra-basic-black-wood-bg.png') repeat;
  border-image-slice: 100 fill;
  border-image-width: 100px;
  border-style: inset;
  transform-origin: 0px 0px;
  transform: matrix(0.344, 0, 0, 0.344, 162.4, 0); /* keep this line */
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="frame"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Which you can find on:

https://codesandbox.io/s/q8nm9v2k34

Here there is a preview:

https://q8nm9v2k34.codesandbox.io

My problem is that on `Chrome` there are some small gaps like division lines as you can see on the following images:

**Chrome:** - BAD (please, notice the tiny division lines on the corners)

[image]

**Firefox:** - OK

[image]

Here you have the stats:

**Window:**

- Chrome: BAD
- Firefox: OK
- Edge: OK

**Mac:**

- Chrome: BAD
- Safari: BAD

Could you please, fork my `Codesandbox.io` above, apply your solution, and paste its link here?

Thanks!

Comment: Does adding vendor prefixes help (ie `-webkit-border-image`, `-moz-border-image`, etc....)?

Comment: nope, it didnt help

Comment: are you open to slice the image into 8 small images and you will be able to avoid this issue?

Comment: unfortunately this is not an option for me. I'm forced to use that existing image for the border

Comment: *I'm forced* : you mean that the person who want this don't want you to find a solution? I don't think there is a trivial solution to border-image and subpixel rendring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea is to split the image and add more background layers and you can have a better result.

```css
.frame {
    display: block;
    width: 800px;
    height: 1000px;
    background: 
      url(https://i.ibb.co/wQSgvS7/jessica.jpg) center/500px 700px no-repeat padding-box, 
      url(https://i.ibb.co/1ssy41c/mcol-papyrus-bg.png) padding-box,
      /* Corners */
      url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvoN2.png) bottom left /100px 100px border-box no-repeat,
      url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzJik.png) top    left /100px 100px border-box no-repeat,
      url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/0r7ag.png) top    right/100px 100px border-box no-repeat,
      url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yWVf.png) bottom right/100px 100px border-box no-repeat,
      /* Borders */
      url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mhf03.png) bottom/100px 100px border-box repeat-x,
      url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/h51w6.png) left  /100px 100px border-box repeat-y,
      url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jt4uz.png) top   /100px 100px border-box repeat-x,
      url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/sp0wZ.png) right /100px 100px border-box repeat-y;
    border: 100px solid transparent;
    transform-origin: 0px 0px;
    transform: matrix(0.344, 0, 0, 0.344, 162.4, 0); /* keep this line */  
  }
body { 
 background:pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="frame"></div>
```

Comment: thank you Temani for your attention, but unfortunately this is not an option for me. I'm not able to divide the initial image into multiple ones

Comment: @davidesp actually it's the only solution I see, by the way what is the purpose of the transform? can't you use a different value and adjust the width/height?

Comment: changing the values could be another approach that would work for me, but I still need to use the original border image because the size of the frame is variable. Here I created another thread about that approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56104265 Could you give it a look?

Answer (score 0):

I've found you can make this look a lot better by setting a background color close to the border color.

Unforutnately, this falls apart if you need the element to scroll, because with scrollbars, Chrome puts the background color on top of the background image