# CSS - Scale border image to the border width or to a specific percentage

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following code:

```css
.container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 344px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 245, 187);
}
.frame {
  margin: 0px auto;
  width: 275.2px;
  height: 344px;
  /*
   * Available border images. The goal is to use image [1]:
   * - [1] https://i.ibb.co/6nW3dZC/fra-silver-cloud-wood-bg.png
   * - [2] https://i.ibb.co/YtVcXn2/fra-silver-cloud-wood-bg-resized.png
  */
  background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/wQSgvS7/jessica.jpg"), url("https://i.ibb.co/h7CCwc5/mcol-bottle-blue-bg.png");
  background-size: 172px 240.8px, auto;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;
  border-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/YtVcXn2/fra-silver-cloud-wood-bg-resized.png") 34.4 fill / 34.4px / 0 repeat;
  border-width: 0;
  border-style: inset;
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <div class="frame"></div>
  </div>
```

which renders the following:

[image]

On the case above it is using for the border, the image: `[2]` (resized version).

Here you have the `Codesandbox.io`:

https://codesandbox.io/s/545l6olpv4

Here you have the preview:

https://545l6olpv4.codesandbox.io/

**My problem is** I cannot use that resized image `[2]`. Instead, I must use image `[1]`.

```
SizeOf([Image 2]) = 0.344 * SizeOf([Image 1])
```

But if for the border I use image `[1]` (target image), then the code above renders the following:

[image]

Any idea on how to make the code above work with image `[1]` for the border?

Please, provide back your solution in a forked `Codesandbox.io`.

Thanks!

Comment: like this: https://jsfiddle.net/5L4htsmf/ ?

Comment: the output on the link you provided is not similar to my first image (the goal). This is what I got from your link above: https://i.ibb.co/WGvCzzf/image.png. This is the gaol: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOUiN.png. Thanks!

Comment: you double the slice: https://jsfiddle.net/5L4htsmf/1/

Comment: thank you Temani, you saved my day: I had to change: `34.4 fill` to `100 fill`

Answer (score 0):

Below is the solution:

Basically needed to change: `100 fill` to `34.4 fill`. Thanks `@temani-afif`!.

```css
.container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 344px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 245, 187);
}

.frame {
  margin: 0px auto;
  width: 275.2px;
  height: 344px;
  background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/wQSgvS7/jessica.jpg"), url("https://i.ibb.co/h7CCwc5/mcol-bottle-blue-bg.png");
  background-size: 172px 240.8px, auto;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;
  /*
       * Available border images. The goal is to use image [1]:
       * - [1] https://i.ibb.co/6nW3dZC/fra-silver-cloud-wood-bg.png
       * - [2] https://i.ibb.co/YtVcXn2/fra-silver-cloud-wood-bg-resized.png
      */
  border-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/6nW3dZC/fra-silver-cloud-wood-bg.png") 100 fill / 34.4px / 0 repeat;
  border-width: 0;
  border-style: inset;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Scale border image to the border width</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="frame"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```